# How do I setup my domain provider's mail forwarding with route53?

Tags: email, dns, amazon-route53, email-forwarding

I registered my domain with Google domains which has a free email forwarding service, but for various reasons (main site is s3-based w/ cloudfront, amazon's free ssl, etc.) I decided to use route53 as the domains dns.

Doing this shows a warning on google domains that my email is now disabled and I have to restore the google domains nameservers.

[image: google domains]

Aside from trying to setup an EC2 instance running postfix to do domain forwarding, is there an easy way to still use my original mail forwarding setup with route53?

Answer (score 2):

As learned from a comment in a [similar reddit question](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/3w84tj/forwarding_emails_with_route_53_not_a_mail_server/), with most domain registrars they're actually running a service to do mail forwarding. Assuming they don't actually disable your mail forwarding when changing the dns records to somewhere else, all you need to do is figure out the registrar's mx servers for forwarding.

In my scenario I did the following steps:

1. Recorded my current working dns setup with route53 to a text file for notes.
2. Clicked the blue 'restore the google domain name servers' button which reset everything. this is temporary.
3. Wait a couple minutes for the dns changes to take effect, then in a unix shell type "dig mx mydomain.com", copy the answer section of this.
4. Set your dns servers for the domain to point back to route53 again.
5. Log into route53 for your domain, create a MX record set using the domains you got when using dig to get your domain registrar's mx records in step 3. Mine looked similar to this:

   [image: route53 mx record entry]

Comment: Worked perfectly. I'm hosting with an AWS EC2 instance, and forwarding back to my domain registrar.